# How to send data to servlet using ajax without a submitting form

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am new with servlet, I am able to get data from the servlet  but not able to send data to it and I want to do this without using a submitting form, can i get some help please

on the click of the button it will go to the servlet and return the text but not the value send to it

This is my index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SO question 4112686</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {                       
            $('#somebutton').click(function() {               
                $.get('GetUserServlet', function(responseText) { 
                    $('#somediv').text(responseText);        
                });
            });
        });
        $("#somebutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
        {
            url:'GetUserServlet',
            data:{name:'abc'},
            type:'get',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){alert(data);},
            error:function(){alert('error');}
        }
    );
}
);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="somebutton" onclick="showHint('GetUserServlet.java',   'travis');">press here</button>
    <div id="somediv"></div>
</body>
```

this my servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String text = "Update Sucessful";
String name = request.getParameter("name");


response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
response.getWriter().write( name + text);       // Write response body.
```

Comment: never used it before  but i am willing to try

Comment: On second look, you already are :) Those $ are jQuery calls.  So you're already using the jQuery.ajax() function.  Give me a few to look at my existing ajax/servlet interactions to remember how it all works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could either use $.ajax() or $.post here. since you have used $.ajax(). please refer below correction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SO question 4112686</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {                       
            $('#somebutton').click(function() {               
                $.get('GetUserServlet', function(responseText) { 
                    $('#somediv').text(responseText);        
                });
            });
        });


        $("#somebutton").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url:'GetUserServlet',
            data:{name:'abc'},
            type:'get',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
               alert(data);
               $('#somediv').text(responseText); 
            },
            error:function(){
              alert('error');
            }
         }
    );
}
);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
    <div id="somediv"> </div>
</body>
```

**and your servlet should be:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GetUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    String text = "Update successfull"; //message you will recieve 
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(name + " " + text);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use $.post method for this purpose.

Here is my solution
**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>SO question 4112686</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#somebutton").click(function() {
             servletCall();
         });

     });
     function servletCall() {
         $.post(
             "GetUserServlet", 
             {name : "Message from jsp"}, //meaasge you want to send
             function(result) {
             $('#somediv').html('Here is your result : <strong>' + result + '</strong>'); //message you want to show
         });
     };
   </script>
</head>
<body>
     <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
     <div id="somediv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**GetUserServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GetUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String text = "<br>Message from servlet<br>"; //message you will recieve 
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(text + name);
}
}
```