# Ajax Request Sending Multiple Items/Javascript Object to Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, http-request-parameters

At first I was sending data over as one singular object like so:

```
function ajaxCall(){
    $.ajax({

                url: "someURL",
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                //more ajax stuff
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#htmlForm").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        data = $("#htmlForm").serialize();
        ajaxCall();
    });
});
```

And on the java back end I would receive my request parameters individually like so:

```
firstRequestParam,
secondRequestParam,
etc..
```

However, there is a new addition which looks like this:

```
function ajaxCall(jsonStuff){
    $.ajax({

                url: "someURL",
                data: {data: data, jsonStuff: jsonStuff}, 
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                //more ajax stuff
});
```

Now on the back end I get this:

```
firstRequestParam = data,
secondRequestParam = jsonStuff
```

What is the best way to get my individual request parameters back now that they are jumbled up and stored as the first property in the javascript object?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate.  I understand how ajax works. I am able to send the data over properly in the javascript object. I am having trouble extracting the data on the java side since the data is now all wrapped up into one single request parameter instead of split up into multiple request paramaters.  Previously if I had 3 fields text fields in the HTML form, if I did `request.getParameter(paramName);` they would come in as: `field1`, `field2`, `field3`. Now, if I do the same `request.getParameter(paramName);` I get: `data`, `jsonStuff`.

Comment: `data` and `jsonStuff` contain what your javascript sent. What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: What u mean by Java ?Servlet in Jee , Controller of Spring MVC , Controllerof JSF ????

Comment: this is how ajax works, what is your problem again? I didn't get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data to servlet using ajax without a submitting form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168646/how-to-send-data-to-servlet-using-ajax-without-a-submitting-form)

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI It is a Java Servlet in JEE.  At first I was extracting the request params simply by doing `request.getParameter(paramName)` using if else statements, which worked before since ajax sent over the `data` from the HTML form individually for each field. Now, each field is not sent over individually, but is wrapped up all in one into the `data` property of of the javascript object.

Comment: Both examples are being POST'd

Comment: what specifically does "data" and "jsonStuff" look like?  the "data" arg of ajax() should be serialized per the rules outlined in jquery.param (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) - are you not seeing these keys in HttpServletRequest?  are you _actually_ seeing httpServletRequest.getParameter("firstRequestParameter") return a non-null value?